# How can I filter results depending on post data using selects and inputs?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a form that contains 3 selects and 3 inputs, plus the submit button. When I submit the form I'm trying to filter the search results by all these inputs and select $_POST values, but when I don't complete all the inputs and select an option for every select I have no results. What am I doing wrong here:

```html
<div style='float: left; margin-right: 20px;'>
 <form action='' method="post">
  <select name='post_type'>
   <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Alege post type</option>    
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['post_type']) && $_POST['post_type'] == 'post') echo 'selected'; ?> value='post'>Post</option>
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['post_type']) && $_POST['post_type'] == 'page') echo 'selected'; ?> value='page'>Page</option>
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['post_type']) && $_POST['post_type'] == 'retete') echo 'selected'; ?> value='retete'>Retete</option>
  </select>
  <select name='post_status'>
   <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Alege status</option>    
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['post_status']) && $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish') echo 'selected'; ?> value='publish'>Publish</option>
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['post_status']) && $_POST['post_status'] == 'trash') echo 'selected'; ?> value='trash'>Trash</option>
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['post_status']) && $_POST['post_status'] == 'draft') echo 'selected'; ?> value='draft'>Draft</option>
  </select>
  <select name='meta_key'>
   <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Alege meta_key</option>    
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['meta_key']) && $_POST['meta_key'] == 'reteta_vizual') echo 'selected'; ?> value='reteta_vizual'>reteta_vizual</option>
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['meta_key']) && $_POST['meta_key'] == 'ingrediente') echo 'selected'; ?> value='ingrediente'>ingrediente</option>
   <option <?php if(isset($_POST['meta_key']) && $_POST['meta_key'] == 'preparare') echo 'selected'; ?> value='preparare'>preparare</option>
  </select>
  <input type='text' name='date_begin' placeholder='Data inceput ("yyyy/mm/dd")' style='width: 200px;'>
  <input type='text' name='date_end' placeholder='Data sfarsit ("yyyy/mm/dd")' style='width: 200px;'>
  <input type='text' name='meta_value' placeholder='Meta value here'>
  <input type='submit' name='filter_results' value='Filtreaza rezultate'>
 </form>
</div>
 <?php
 //filter 
 echo "<table class='wp-list-table widefat fixed posts'>";
  echo "<thead>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Post title</th>";
    echo "<th>Author</th>";
   echo "</tr>";
  echo "</thead>";
 if(isset($_POST['filter_results'])){
  $tabel_1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
  $tabel_2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
  $post_status = $_POST['post_status'];
  $post_type = $_POST['post_type'];
  $meta_key = $_POST['meta_key'];
  $date_begin = $_POST['date_begin'];
  $date_end = $_POST['date_end'];
  var_dump($_POST);
  $records_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tabel_1 AS posts 
           INNER JOIN $tabel_2 AS postmeta 
           ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id 
           WHERE posts.post_status = '$post_status' 
           AND posts.post_type = '$post_type' 
           AND postmeta.meta_key = '$meta_key'
           AND posts.post_date BETWEEN '$date_begin' AND '$date_end'
           GROUP BY posts.ID");
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($records_posts);
  foreach($records_posts as $single_post){
   $author_id = $single_post->post_author;
   $author_name = get_the_author_meta('nicename', $author_id);
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $single_post->post_id . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $single_post->post_title . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $author_name . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: If you create a filter, you only need to search fields that are selected/filled in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the blank values in query like below :

```
$all_conditions = '';

if($post_status != "")
    $conditions[] = "posts.post_status = '".$post_status."'";

if($post_type != "")
    $conditions[] = "posts.post_type = '".$post_type."'";

if($meta_key != "")
    $conditions[] = "postmeta.meta_key = '".$meta_key."'";

if($date_begin != "" && $date_end != "")
    $conditions[] = "( posts.post_date BETWEEN '".$date_begin."' AND '".$date_end."' )";

if(count($conditions)>0)
    $all_conditions = implode(" and ",$conditions);

if($all_conditions != "")
    $all_conditions = "where ".$all_conditions;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabel_1 AS posts INNER JOIN $tabel_2 AS postmeta ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id $all_conditions GROUP BY posts.ID"

$records_posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Please check it again. I have fixed that.

Comment: It works. Can you please explain a little what you did? What $conditions[ ] are? Thank you.

Comment: @Anonymous Great. :) For explanation, I added `if` conditions to check whether posted value is not `blank`. If its not `blank` then only you should include it in query.

Comment: but what $conditions[ ] mean? I'm confused a little about the [ ].

Comment: I added all the `conditions` in an `array` and then imploded the `array` to convert into `string` so that it can be passed to query. Another way can be create a string and then pass it to string.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. Thank you for your explanation and for your answer.